# Download postview image in original size

Tags: camera, sony, image-size, remoteapi

Trying to download the postview image in original size I'm getting an error on setting "Postview image size" parameter to "Original". Downloading (and setting) the postview image with "2M" size is working well.
Are there any undocumented limitations on downloading original sized postview images?

My camera model is ILCE 5100 with latest firmware installed.

Edit:

json request:

```
{'method': 'setPostviewImageSize', 'params': ["Original"], 'id': 1, 'version': '1.0'}
```

response:

```
{'id': 1, 'error': [1, "Failed: couldn't set postview size."]}
```

Replacing "Original" with "2M" the response is

```
{'id': 1, 'result': [0]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error could be a result of not having a memory card inserted into the camera. Do you have one inserted?

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me was to update the Smart Remote Control app on the camera. This allowed the call to setPostviewImageSize to succeed now.