# postview image in original size

Tags: camera, sony, sony-camera-api

(a similar issue was asked before [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31138813/6640545)], but the answers provided there don't really help me)

My camera is a DSC-W500, running Smart Remote Control Ver. 4.10 (no further updates offered). The camera has a memory card with plenty of space available.

I am capturing images using actTakePicture().

The problem is that I can only set Postview Image Size to 2M.

getSupportedPostviewImageSize() returns [["Original", "2M"]]

getAvailablePostviewImageSize() returns ["2M",["2M"]]

setPostviewImageSize() obviously fails when trying with ["Original"]

So all I get now is a 2M image instead of full size.

what am I missing?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It is strange that getAvailablePostviewImageSize() is not returning "Original" as an option.  I would suggest checking that your memory card is formatted and installed correctly.